# 360 Degree PNG Sequence Drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I have a PNG sequence of 360 images (1 image per degree of rotation). I currently have a React component that renders the current degree of rotation based on the mouse position inside the window, where x = 0 is rotation = 1 and x = `window.innerWidth` is rotation = 360.

```
// Map a set of min/max values to another set of min/max values based on the given value
const map = (value, x1, y1, x2, y2) => (value - x1) * (y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1) + x2;

class Rotation extends Component {
    startX = 0;
    lastX = 0;
    pointerDown = false;

    state = {
        rotation: 1,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.handlePointerDown);
        window.addEventListener('pointerup', this.handlePointerUp);
        window.addEventListener('pointermove', this.handlePointerMove);
    }

    handlePointerDown = event => {
        this.startX = event.pageX;
        this.pointerDown = true;
    };

    handlePointerUp = () => {
        this.pointerDown = false;
    };

    handlePointerMove = event => {
        if (!this.pointerDown) {
            return;
        }
        const rotation = Math.round(map(event.pageX, 0, window.innerWidth, 1, 360));
        this.setState({rotation});
    };

    render() {
        return <img src={`/img/rotation/${this.state.rotation}.png`}/>
    }
}
```

The problem I have is a jumping in the rotation, where I start dragging from the middle of the screen and the image jumps to 180 degrees. I'm struggling to get it to rotate based on the last rotation position. I'd like it to rotate based on the distance I've moved from the startX location. Is this something that can be done with math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the current rotation when the user starts dragging and use the offset as a delta rather than an absolute rotation.

```
class Rotation extends Component {
    startX = 0;
    lastX = 0;
    pointerDown = false;

    state = {
        rotation: 1,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.handlePointerDown);
        window.addEventListener('pointerup', this.handlePointerUp);
        window.addEventListener('pointermove', this.handlePointerMove);
    }

    handlePointerDown = event => {
        this.startX = event.pageX;
        this.startRotation = this.state.rotation;
        this.pointerDown = true;
    };

    handlePointerUp = () => {
        this.pointerDown = false;
    };

    handlePointerMove = event => {
        if (!this.pointerDown) {
            return;
        }
        // If you want to rotate the other way, invert the subtraction
        const offset = 360 * (event.pageX - this.startX) / window.innerWidth;
        let newRotation = this.startRotation + offset;
        // Need to offset by 1 before the modulo since it works between 0-359
        newRotation = ((newRotation - 1) % 360) + 1;
        if (newRotation <= 0) newRotation += 360;
        this.setState({ rotation: newRotation });
    };

    render() {
        return <img src={`/img/rotation/${this.state.rotation}.png`}/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works brilliantly. For my implementation I needed whole numbers and non-zero values, so I had to add `newRotation = Math.round(Math.max(1, newRotation));` before the setState call. Thanks again